# React conditional className the class name itself is changing but css is not updating

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I'm adding to a current project. I'm working with a parent and child component. When a marker is clicked on a map I need to conditionally change the className within the child component.

Code within `Parent` component has two divs affected by Parents state. The first div works correctly and slides up like it should. But the `ChildComponent` only changes the className without the actual css taking affect.

```js
<ParentComponent>
  <div>
    <div className={`${this.state.openCard ? 'container-opened' : 'container'}`}>
      ...
    </div>
    <ChildComponent displayCard={this.state.openCard} />
  </div>
</>
```

Here is code of Child Component.

```js
const ChildComponent = props => {
  ...
  return (
    <div id='marker' className={`${props.displayCard ? "opened" : "closed"}`}>
      <Card />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Like I said I'm trying to get the css to apply. What am I missing? When the prop switches it removes the className and css from `ChildComponent` but it only adds the className and not the needed css itself. Side note project was created with CRA and is SSR.

Comment: Is the CSS for the two classes defined in the same file as each other?  Are they both imported?

Comment: Sorry should of included that. There is one css file in the parent div which applies to the first `<div>`. Then I have a css file within `ChildComponent` because there is other styling for it. Both are imported.

Comment: Could you provide a working example? Maybe there're some import issues. By the way, in REACT you should avoid using `id` on HTML element, because of the re-usability of the components

Comment: It could be that the class rules are not specific enough to over ride other rules. Very hard to troubleshoot this without a running [mcve]. Do you see the rule(s) in the style tree of dev tools element inspector but below other specificity rules?

Comment: The import themselves are working because they both have initial css applied from those files.

Comment: I am a big fan of testing, so if I were you , I would do a console log in the child component to check if the prop is changing and also if the component is re rendering.

Comment: Even if css was overridden in chrome dev tools shouldn’t it at least be shown as applied and then obviously would just be overridden by my specific rules?

Comment: I did test for prop change. Can confirm the prop is changing correctly

Comment: I do not show the changed rules within the style tree at all. That’s what is throwing me off

Comment: Where have you imported the css file corresponding to the child component? In the child or in the parent? Have you tried importing it in both places?

Comment: Again, a working example is what we need to properly help you. Anyways, you can do one more test: instead of assigning the `className`, try update the `style`, just for testing. So, write `<div id='marker' style={props.displayCard ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'green' }}>`.

Comment: Can you actually show us the css code which shows the defining of the class styling ?

Comment: Haha I’ve tried updating the styling conditionally also. Let me see if I can come up with working example. This may be stupid question but easy way to set up a working example with ssr cra?

Comment: One last question considering what I’ve written up top does my code look correct considering that?